# Dynamically updating basic_qos prefetch to prevent prefetched messages while workers remain busy after ack

Tags: multithreading, rabbitmq, amqp, multiprocess

I'm looking for performance concerns or other gotchas around dynamically adjusting the prefetch count. And of course I'm also welcoming better solutions.

In my scenario I have 10 worker threads to which my consumer distributes messages. Naturally, I have a prefetch count of 10 so that they may all receive work concurrently.

This is a problem if I want to ack the message early on and do a longer running task in the worker.  When my worker acks and proceeds to do more work, Rabbit will prefetch the next head message, potentially causing that message to be delayed while other workers (in a totally different process) are available to handle it.

I'm imagining a solution where my consumer decrements the prefetch count before distributing a message to a worker, and then incrementing it again once that worker completes.

**To summarize the problem & proposed solution:**

Workers may not become available right after ACKing a message, causing the next prefetched message to be needlessly delayed.

The consumer who distributes messages to workers can adjust the prefetch count based on the business of indvididual workers.

Comment: Not sure which language client you are using. But if you are using java client you don't need to manage threads explicitly for processing messages in parallel. Updated my post with the same finding.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like performance tuning scenario. You need to understand

1. frequency of messages over a period of time.
2. processing time (time take by your worker threads in processing the message) variance. Whether the processing time is more or less same for each message or its uneven.

One logical solution that you could do is (if you are able to identify the number of worker threads waiting for processing message) that you reset the prefetch count to number of available threads and send a basic ack to rabbitmq. i.e. after every worker thread processing completion (i.e. worker thread becomes available) you send these

```
channel.basicQos(no_of_available_worker_threads); 
channel.basicAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false);
```

**e.g. Just assume a scenario where** 
You have just started with prefetch limit 10. You have received 4 messages. So now 4 worker threads are busy processing the messages. Then one of your completes processing and becomes available for next message. At this moment you have 7 worker threads waiting. Now, you will send

```
channel.basicQos(7); 
channel.basicAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false);
```

Now your consumer receives 3 more messages from rabbitmq. You have now 4 worker threads waiting. Now one more worker thread becomes availble. Now, you will send

```
channel.basicQos(5); 
channel.basicAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false);
```

After some time one more thread becomes available. Now, you will send

```
channel.basicQos(4); 
channel.basicAck(envelope.getDeliveryTag(), false);
```

and so on....

so your consumer will never receive more no of messages than available workers at that moment.

**Update -**

**I am not sure which language client you are using. But if you are using java client (I tested with amqp-client5.0.0.jar), the consumer (created as in below code) always creates a new thread when it receives a new message, after processing the message the thread is destroyed. You don't have to manage threads for processing messages in parallel. So at any given time you will never have more threads than  the QOS limit you have set.**

```
Consumer consumer = new DefaultConsumer(channel) {
              @Override
              public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag, Envelope envelope, AMQP.BasicProperties properties, byte[] body)
                  throws IOException {
                String message = new String(body, "UTF-8");
                System.out.println("Received '" + message + "'");
                //process message
        };
channelSet.basicConsume(queueName, true, consumer);
```

Comment: This answer affirms the technique I seek.  Re-reading over my question I now realize that I didn't ask what I really wanted to.  I want to know if from the perspective of RabbitMQ, if adjusting the prefetch is a bad practice or even abusive.  Is it painful for RMQ to keep track of that QOS option on the channel if it's in constant flux?

Comment: I assume setting QOS must have some overhead. If you have high volume of messages with low message processing time then setting QOS frequently may not be a better option. This link may provide some help in finding an approach for tuning QOS limit. - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/issues/644